# Generalized eiganvalue problem

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have the equation
$$M \Psi - \epsilon \Psi = b \, ,$$
where M is a $N \times N$ matrix and $\Psi, b$ are $N-$dimensional vectors where $b$ is known and has the form $b = (b_L, 0, \dots, 0, b_R)$. $\epsilon$ is a scalar. Are there any numerical methods to find $\Psi_n, \epsilon_n$ that solve my equation?

Comment: You can rewrite it as $$(M-\epsilon I)\Psi=b$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Thus you are left with the classical problem $A \Psi=b$.

Comment: Ok but I would have to speficy $\epsilon$ to calculate the inverse of $A$, and $\epsilon$ is what I want to calculate. Or would I demand that $det(A) =0$ but then I would get the exact same eigenvalues as in the case where $b=0$, which does not make sense for me.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point.